# The $T$-group of order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Among the groups of order $12$, an exceptional group is the $T$-group which is semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $\mathbb{Z}_4$. This group is discussed in many texts but it is described in terms of generators and relations. I didn't find any other simple description of this group which can be easily explained to undergraduates with less machinery.

**Q.** Is there any simple description of the group $T$ without generators and relations?

Comment: What's wrong with "semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $\mathbb{Z}_4$"?

Comment: Rotations of tetrahedron, maybe?

Comment: @Ivan: No, that (your) group is not the T group.

Comment: @Beginner That's interesting, because crystallographers tend to call my group exactly that (T). But I got you now; yours is a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $T$ can be found e.g. within the special linear group $SL_2(5)$ of $2$-by-$2$ matrices with determinant $1$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_5$ with $5$ elements, so you may want to describe it as something like

$$T=\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle$$